# Lager yeast fermenting at 25-30C

Tags: yeast, fermentation-temperature

The summer is approaching, and I would like to make some experiments using lager yeast, just completely out of its temperature range. I guess that steam bear was made using lager yeast at higher temperature. So I want to try using lager (I previously wrote ale by mistake) yeast at relatively hot temperature. What should I expect? Just a beer that tastes not right or may something interesting come?

**EDIT:** Sorry for the inconvenience, I meant lager yeast.

Comment: are you planning to use lager or ale yeast? you mention using both.

Comment: @mdma: lager, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mdma is right, your question is a little confusing.

You already described what you get when you ferment lager yeast at warm temps - A California Common (or Steam beer). California Common is typically very malty with fruity notes, and generally a good amount of hob bitterness.

When you ferment Ale yeast warm you get a saison.

You can expect a whole lot of esters. Saison yeast is ale yeast that has a lot of pleasant spicy/clovey esters that really stand out when fermented hot.

You need to be sure to do your research before you ferment out of recommended temperatures. Some yeast work, some will be awful. Wyeast 2124 and 2112 have produced good results fermenting warm.

Comment: I don't think it's quite that clear cut. I think any lager yeast at high temps will be quite revolting - the steam beer yeast has acclimatized to fermenting warmer. Ferment a wheat yeast warm and you get bubblegum, not really Saison!

Comment: there are definitely some lager yeasts you can ferment warm. highlighted in this brewing TV episode. http://brewingtv.com/episodes/2012/3/2/brewing-tv-episode-53-lager-workarounds.html. I will update my answer to be more clear about types of yeast.

Answer (score 2):

I just kegged a lager that I fermented at 67 F (19.5 C), and am drinking the "overflow" right now. It's been six days since pitching (WLP 830) and the beer is quite drinkable.

I ferment in a 10 gallon Cornelius keg. After reading that fermenting under pressure can help with reducing esters formation in lagers, I decided to do an experiment. I fermented one batch at 53 F. at atmospheric pressure. I did another batch with the same recipe, but fermented at 67 F., under 25 psi of pressure.

I plan on doing a side-by-side comparison soon, but from the first taste I can say that it's definitely a lager. I'm tasting a very small amount of fruitiness (esters), and a little bit of butter (diacetyl), but no more than what I've tasted in some micro-brewery lagers.

This is not a very good answer to your question, as you're probably not set up to ferment under pressure, and ambient temperatures in Canada are considerably lower than where you are, but I wanted to make this point: it's possible to ferment a lager at room temperature and not produce a estery, buttery abomination of a beer.